# meaning of noun FLAG

Tags: word-meaning

> Mitch McConnell’s re-election campaign slapped with FEC `flag` over suspected accounting errors

It's an article title from [Salon](https://www.salon.com/2020/09/24/mitch-mcconnells-re-election-campaign-slapped-with-fec-flag-over-suspected-accounting-errors_partner/). I know the usual meaning of `flag` but in the sentence it doesn't seem to make sense. If the `flag` is a verb with `flagging` I can understand it as `marking` but the noun doesn't have the meaning in my english dictionaries.

What does the `flag` mean in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Flag* here is a warning that the authorities believe a rules violation has occurred.

It is a sports metaphor deriving from the conventional meaning of *flag* as a piece of cloth that is used as a symbol or signal of something. Specifically, the usage comes from American football (other sports like lacrosse also use flags, but football is by far the most popular). If a referee observes a rules violation, he or she stops play by literally throwing a [penalty flag](https://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nfl/penalty-flag.aspx) at the location where the infraction occurred

McConnell receiving a flag is thus the FEC stating they believe he has violated the law, and should stop those activities until they can be reviewed by the officials.

Answer (score 1):

A "flag" can mean "A marker used to indicate that an item needs further attention".

For example in my email, I can put a flag on an email to remind myself that that email contains something that I will need to do.

Here the Federal Election Commission (FEC) has put a flag (figuratively) on the campaign, it means that the FEC will need to give further attention to the campaign.